# Best Way to Stream GMail API

Tags: api, gmail, websocket, sinatra, real-time

I'm building a web application using GMails IMAP API. What would be the best way for me to make the updates "real-time"?

As of right now I'm using a Ruby Sinatra backend and backbone.js on the frontend. I'm looking for a way to make the communication between my frontend, my server, and the gmail api to be as fast and seamless as possible.

Thanks for the help

Edit: what I mean is what is the best way to make it seem real time. I realize gmail does not support web sockets. But what would be a good way of setting up my server and front end to make the data transaction as frictionless as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. HTTP does not work this way. You would need [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for this, but Gmail API does not support WebSocket.

You can either update info often (but you will run into google api request number limits).
Or update info when user needs it (that needs careful planning).

Comment: Okay yeah my phrasing was a little off. What I meant was what is the best way to make it seem real time. I realize that if I use web sockets I will need to use my server as a proxy for the data. I was just wondering if anyone else has had experience and would be willing to share some tips